# Multi-class LDA (pairwise classification)

Tags: classification, linear-algebra, discriminant-analysis, multi-class

From this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/453732):

$ w=S_{W}^{-1}(μ1−μ2), $

is used to estimate

$w_{0}=\frac{1}{2}(μ_{1}−μ_{2})^{T}S_{W}^{-1}(μ_{1}−μ_{2})−log(\frac{P1}{P2}),$

However, this is for a situation where there are only 2 classes. How can i adapt this so it can be applied to n number of classes (say 3 classes).

On Wikipedia, it's mentioned that:

> Another common method is pairwise classification, where a new classifier is created for each pair of classes (giving C(C − 1)/2 classifiers in total), with the individual classifiers combined to produce a final classification.

But, how is this expressed in a similar way/formula to the above? Thanks.

Comment: Your title is ambiguous. Either you are asking about LDA with k classes, or about a series of 2-class LDA classifiers.

Comment: @ttnphns Sorry, it would be LDA with k classes.

Comment: LDA with k classes is Rao's canonical LDA. It has two stages: extraction of discriminants and classification by them. There is a great number of posts here about it. Including a number of mine. Search the tag "discriminant-analysis".

Comment: @ttnphns I tried searching for more information on Rao's canonical LDA, but google search results direct me back to just regular LDA. Furthermore, if you meant the post where you linked a lot of answeres, I have mostly checked that out beforehand and found it a bit overwhelming. This was the closest (I think) that got me more information https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22891/307324

Comment: Canonical LDA is the "regular LDA" in multiclass situation. In the link you display, follow the link in my answer there and then the further links behind it.